# In AppleScript, how can I make a dialog box with a custom icon?

Tags: applescript

In AppleScript, how can you make a dialog box with a custom icon in the app bundle?

I'd like it to be in the Contents/Resources directory, and named "GenericNetworkIcon.icns".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the icon into …`.app/Contents/Resources/`, as you said. It can then referenced directly, without using comparitively-fragile file aliases, by using the [`path to resource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW20) command from the File Commands suite of [AppleScript Commands](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html).

```
display dialog "theguy123" with icon {path to resource "GenericNetworkIcon.icns"}
```

[image: screenshot of a the above line of code in action, including icon]